# Better performance than document.createElement

Tags: javascript, performance

So, i have some piece of code that dynamically creates a lot of different inputs, and the execution of this specific piece of code is really slow.
Every document.createElement that runs is taking around 80 milliseconds, do you guys know something that could replace this createElement command?

[image: createElement running slowly]

```
{  
 oElement = frame.createElement('input');   
 oElement.type = 'hidden';  
 oElement.name = 'cdcategor';  
 oElement.id = 'cdcategor';  
 oElement.value = '311';  
 fragment.appendChild(oElement);   
}
```

Comment: createElement and innerHTML are your two choices really. Guess you could also clone an element....

Comment: innerHTML might be faster, as the DOM doesnt have to be recalculated at every iteration.

Comment: You can't get much better with element creation than `createElement`. Chrome is showing accumulated time spent on a certain portion of code -- it's not very line-wise precise.

Comment: By "accumulated" I mean that it counts all iterations of a, for example, for loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, i think that for every "frame" access, if it already has lots of nodes, it takes longer, can this be it?

Comment: Try leveraging [`createDocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment).  You are likely inserting your nodes directly after creation which causes full reflows.

Comment: It was taking 40 seconds to load the full page, i created a fragment and now it is faster (now it takes around 12 seconds), but it still has performance issues.  
It is a big loop with around 200 items,

Comment: Shouldn't this be a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)? We're talking about working code that might need improvement after all..

Comment: @icecub it could also be, i have a repeating loop with around 200 items that generates javascript code, which is later printed to a page.

Comment: Maybe if you showed more code, people could spot other ways to improve it.